# Python: requests hang for hours

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using `requests` to resolve urls for about 410K check-in data. However, the process hang somewhere for hours and I am not sure where the problem is. I did the same thing for 1.7M pieces of data before and it worked well. Here is my code:

```
pat = re.compile("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)") # always compile it
def resolve_url(text):
    url = 'before'
    long_url = 'after'
    error = 'none'
    match = pat.search(text)
    if match:
        url = match.group("url")
        try:
            long_url = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True).url
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  
            error = e

    return (url, long_url, error)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(200)
resolved_urls = []
for i, res in enumerate(pool.imap(resolve_url, text_with_url)):
    resolved_urls.append(res)
    if i%10000 == 0 and i > 0:
        print("%d elements have been processed, %2.5f seconds" %(i+1, time.time()-t0))
        fout = open("./yangj/resolved_urls_%d_requests.pkl"%(i+1),"w")
        pickle.dump(resolved_urls, fout)
        fout.close()
        resolved_urls = []
fout = open("./yangj/resolved_urls_last_requests.pkl","w")
pickle.dump(resolved_urls, fout)
fout.close()
```

I was wondering whether the problem is because of some exception that I need to write code to recover. I have looked through `requests` documents and previous similar questions but I didn't find matching answers. Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: How many elements are processed successfully? Can't you use your counter to identify which URL is causing a hang? This seems like it could be a very important clue here.

Comment: Have you perhaps got stuck in [a tarpit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarpit_(networking)) due to trying to scrape a website? Your script has no rate-limiting, so I suspect that could be an issue.

Comment: @machineyearning I have processed 21K elements successfully. I am not sure how to focus on the URL which causes the hang-problem, because there are also other elements which can cause exception

Comment: @KenY-N thanks for your comment. Yes this could be a possibility but how to resolve the issue. Should I add rate-limiting as an argument to `requests.head` or should I write a recovering code to deal with it in exception, like sleep for some time?